# Sample size calculation for comparison of 3 proportions

Tags: sampling, sample-size, sample

How do I calculate sample size for estimating difference in proportions between 3 groups? Most of the free sample size calculators have options for only 2 groups.

Comment: please display your data if you have it. if you do not have data, explain your problem eg are you looking for an estimate of sample-size.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to know. If you want to have every group different then it's probably best to do a simulation for your particular case because it depends on the actual expected probabilities in each condition. If you just want any comparison among the three to come out and there's an expected common or similar proportion then you could just do it for one comparison but adjust alpha for the multiple comparisons.

But my guess is that you're asking the wrong question. You want to know the minimum N for detecting a difference. You should be asking what the N is to be able to reasonably accurately estimate the effect. The answer to that question is unrelated to how many tests you want to make and results in a useful outcome regardless of whether tests are significant or not.

Comment: How should I evaluate such an N? and say if that N is 200, and my three groups are well over 300, am I done? thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but it actually sounds like it might be a good CrossValidated question once it is fleshed out and is a little much to answer in the comment section.